# Работа со списком картинок

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь создать список картинок и работать с ним. Помогите мне разобраться с этим. Много чего пересмотрела, ничего похожего не нашла.

```
private List enemy = new ArrayList();//список картинок
```

Чуть ниже идет заполнение списка картинками:

```
enemies = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prizrak1);
enemy.add(new Enemy(this, enemies)); 
enemies = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prizrak2);    
enemy.add(new Enemy(this, enemies)); 
enemies =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prizrak3);        
enemy.add(new Enemy(this, enemies)); 
enemies =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prizrak4);
enemy.add(new Enemy(this, enemies)); 
enemies =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prizrak4);                          
enemy.add(new Enemy(this, enemies));
```

Так ли надо добавлять в список картинки? Я после я хочу генерировать каждый раз случайную картинку и отрисовывать её.

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
while(1>0) {
   Enemy e; 
   int ii=random.nextInt(5)+1; 
   e=enemy.get(ii);
   if(e.x >= 1000 || e.x <= 1000) { 
      e.onDraw(canvas); 
   }
```

Но они не отрисовываются? Тогда как сделать случайный выбор картинки из списка?

Comment: еще такой вопрос, вам прям таки необходимо отрисовывать на канвасе?

Comment: разве можно вызывать callBack методы руками? Я имею ввиду onDraw()

Comment: Тот много ошибок. Как минимум, если у вас есть canvas (откуда он у вас?), то на нем рисовать надо не e.onDraw(), а  canvas.drawBitmap(). Ну и `while(1>0)` - здесь явно что-то не так.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так делать не стоит. Загружать сразу все картинку в память - плохая идея.
Я бы сделал так: сначала заполнил список id всех нужных вам картинок.
А загружал картинку в память уже непосредственно в методе для отрисовки. Ах да, не забудьте еще очищать Bitmap.

Comment: Шта? Если это что-то типа спрайтов, то какой смысл в ленивой загрузке?

Comment: мне кажется про спрайты тут бы уточнили.

Comment: Класс `Enemy` и прорисовка в бесконечном цикле случайных битмапов как бы намекают.

Answer (score 0):

А Picasso или UniversalImageLoader отлично справляется отрисовкой. Особенно если картинок много. И память особо не занимает.